# Setting priority of wireless networks in KDE Network Manager

Tags: wireless, networking, kubuntu, network-manager, kde

Is there a way to determine the priority of wireless networks?

The KDE networkmanager applet works fine, but it often connects to the WRONG wireless network by default when multiple networks are available.

(For example: at work we have a network A that allows printing, but which is not available throughout the building; and a network B that works everywhere, but that does not allow printing. Obviously I want to connect to B only if A is not available, but the networkmanager just seems to prefer B.)

Comment: I haven't seen such feature, but that sound like a good idea, have you considered posting it to http://forum.kde.org/ ?

Comment: I just did. Thanks! I am also still looking for workarounds? Any ideas?

Comment: I saw [your post at KDE's forum](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=122636&hilit=priority+wifi+priority) bit there still not seems to be any convincing solution. Am I right?

Comment: No, nothing yet... :/